# Is this an appropriate method to evaluate a limit.

Tags: limits

Suppose you wish to find some limit of a function $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$. Now suppose further you can bound the functions above and below by two functions $g(x)$, $h(x)$ and that these functions that bound the function of which we want to evaluate the limit both have the same limit as $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Now what about if the boundedness of $f(x)$ only works for sufficiently large $x$ or only works for $x >0$ for example.

I.e.

$g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)~(*)$ only when we put one of the two conditions on $x$ stated above.

Since we are talking about limits as $x$ tends to infinity can we just say whatever let $x$ be "whatever requirement is needed" to ensure $(*)$ holds and then conclude that our limit exists and is equal to the limit of $h,g$ as $x$ tends to infinity?

So it would be appropriate to use squeeze theorem on this limit as $x$ goes to infinity?

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1+\frac{1}{x} ~:\forall x \in \mathbb{Q}\\1 ~:\forall x \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Obviously for negative $x$ we can't bound it but if we set $x>0$ we can.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, take a look at that:

[Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)

Comment: So it would be appropriate to use squeeze theorem on this limit as $x$ goes to infinity? 

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1+\frac{1}{x} ~:\forall x \in \mathbb{Q}\\1 ~:\forall x \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Obviously for negative $x$ we can't bound it but if we set $x>0$ we can.

Comment: Is this a formula for $f(x)$? Then, yes, you can bound it from below by a constant function $g(x)=1$ and from above by $h(x)=1+\frac{1}{x}$. Both of them have limit $1$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$ and for sufficiently large $x$ there's $g(x)\le f(x) \le h(x)$

Comment: Yes this is how the elements are mapped.

Comment: You don't have to worry about what's for $x<0$ or $x<100000$ etc. because you only care about how the function acts as $x$ tends to infinity.  It's implied by the definition of a limit.